# How do I make a table from a List MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a List(Name, Item, Group#) that I would like to display in a table.  How do I display this data with all the names in the 1st row, item in the 2nd, and group number in the 3rd row.

Name:  | Jon | Tom | Kate | Brian |

Item:  | Cup | Hat | Door | Store |

Group#:| 2 | 8 | 10 | 154 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're going horizontally instead of vertically, this makes the code example I've thought up a bit messy. I'm not sure if there's an alternative to this, but this should work.

```
<table class="table">

    <tr>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>    
        <% 
        foreach (var item in Model) 
        {
         %>
            <td>
                <%= item.Name %>
            </td>
        <% 
        } 
        %>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Item
        </td>    
        <% 
        foreach (var item in Model) 
        {
         %>
            <td>
                <%= item.Item %>
            </td>
        <% 
        } 
        %>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Group
        </td>    
        <% 
        foreach (var item in Model) 
        {
         %>
            <td>
                <%= item.Group%>
            </td>
        <% 
        } 
        %>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I usually use the foreach vertically, I was hoping there would be a slicker alternative, but I also didnt think about this one.  Thanks!!!

Comment: An extension method would probably be the nicest way to do this. But the method would basically be doing this anyway.

Comment: Could you do this using just a single foreach?

Comment: @Robin - I've asked the question myself here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012326/how-can-i-create-a-horizontal-table-in-a-single-foreach-loop-in-mvc