# How can I create a horizontal table in a single foreach loop in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model, foreach

Is there any way, in ASP.Net MVC, to condense the following code to a single foreach loop?

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>    
        <% 
        foreach (var item in Model) 
        {
         %>
            <td>
                <%= item.Name %>
            </td>
        <% 
        } 
        %>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Item
        </td>    
        <% 
        foreach (var item in Model) 
        {
         %>
            <td>
                <%= item.Company %>
            </td>
        <% 
        } 
        %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Where model is an `IEnumerable<SomeObject>`:

```
public class SomeObject
{
   public virtual Name {get;set;}
   public virtual Company {get;set;}
}
```

This would output a table as follows:

```
Name     |    Bob    |     Sam    |    Bill   |     Steve    |
Company  |  Builder  |   Fireman  |     MS    |     Apple    |
```

I know I could probably use an extension method to write out each row, but is it possible to build all rows using a single iteration over the model?

This is a follow on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006082/how-do-i-make-a-table-from-a-list-mvc/3006133) as I'm unhappy with my accepted answer and cannot believe I've provided the best solution.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible in a single loop with given condition.good question though :)

Comment: Have you considered using a different construct besides a table? It does not make sense to me in this case. Except for IE6 and maybe 7, the CSS `display: table-cell/table-row` may be worth looking into as an alternative. So no tables-in-tables :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not restricted to using pure tables, then this would work for you.

```
<table class="table"> 
    <tr> 
        <th> 
             Name<br/>
             Item<br/>
        </th>     
        <%  
        foreach (var item in Model)  
        { 
         %> 
            <td> 
                  <%= Html.Encode(item.Name) %><br/>
                  <%= Html.Encode(item.company) %><br/>
            </td> 
        <%  
        }  
        %> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

You can definitely improve this by using span and css stylings.

Comment: Is it legitimate to put a table header within a table row? Anyway, could probably just set the th to a td anyway. Quite a nice example. Must nicer than tables within tables anyway!

Comment: @GeneticTypeTea, it definitely works. Tested on both IE8 and Firefox. Some advantages over "table within tables" 
are :
1) less bandwidth. 
2) easier to style with css.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following mat it help you

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Name</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Item</td></tr>
             <table>
        </td>    
        <% 
        foreach (var item in Model) 
        {
         %>
            <td>
                <table>
                  <tr><td><%= item.Name %></td></tr>
                  <tr><td><%= item.company %></td></tr>
                <table>
            </td>
        <% 
        } 
        %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note:-

```
No check though :)
```

Comment: Heh, clever. I like it, but I feel dirty for liking it. I think I'd prefer my answer over a table>in>table solution, but smart thinking!

Comment: @GenericTypeTea  :- yeah! i agree with u it's dirty. i also don't mind 2 loops over table>in>table solution. But it's just 4 record. Cheer's

Answer (score 0):

Very old thread, but...

I've used the following (but was looking for a better approach when I came across this question)

Create a code block that loops through the objects and creates the HTML for each row in a variable, then output the variable.

The plus is you're only looping once and do not have nested tables (so things are more likely to line up) but the minus is the string manipulation of html.

Should probably use stringbuilder rather than string, but principle is the same.

```
 @code
        Dim tr1 As String = "<th>Name</th>"
        Dim tr2 As String = "<th>Company</th>"

        For Each thingy As object In Model

            tr1 += "<th>" & thingy.Name & "</th>"
            tr2 += "<th>" & thingy.Company & "</th>"

        Next



        End Code

        @<table class="table table-condensed">
            <tr>@Html.Raw(tr1)</tr>
            <tr>@Html.Raw(tr2)</tr>
         </table>
```